# How to detect step changes in GPS time-series data?

Tags: time-series, change-point

The graph below shows GPS heading data (sampled every second) and I am trying to find the best way to detect (right/left) turns in the data. Appreciate suggestions for algorithms/methods for it (perhaps step detection)?

[image: GPS heading sampled 1 sec apart]

While turns typically result in sharp change in heading value, heading might also change gradually due to road curvature which should not be detected.

Comment: You don't just have speed and direction; you can also get velocity components in the east-west and north-south directions. If you look for a step in either or both of those components, that might be more sensitive.

Comment: Typically for solving problems like these, you would use supervised learning. That would require you to have a another time-series, where the steps were manually labeled. Otherwise at least, you will need to know some additional information, such as the number of the turns corresponding to the above series. Is it 2, or is it 12? Unless you have access to some well-known parametric model for steps, you won't have much luck with this one. Speaking of change-points I read an article about this slick shiny app: http://glimmer.rstudio.com/pssguy/TVShowRatings/ check if the method is any good.